# MySQL Row Constructor forms in INSERT VALUES vs. VALUES

Tags: mysql, syntax

In MySQL 8, based on my reading of the documentation, [`INSERT VALUES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html) accepts row constructors in the form:

```
INSERT ... VALUES(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9);
```

or

```
INSERT ... VALUES ROW(1,2,3), ROW(4,5,6), ROW(7,8,9);
```

Either of which results in the values inserted into a table.

However, with [`VALUES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/values.html) used by itself or in a `UNION` for example (in a manner similar to `SELECT`), only the form using `ROW()` works.

```
VALUES ROW(1,2), ROW(3,4);
```

produces

```
+----------+----------+
| column_0 | column_1 |
+----------+----------+
|        1 |        2 |
|        3 |        4 |
+----------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But the form with only parentheses produces a 1064 error "You have an error in your SQL syntax..." even if outer parentheses are added to group the rows.

```
VALUES (1,2), (3, 4);
```

produces

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(1,2), (3, 4)' at line 1

```
VALUES ((1,2), (3, 4));
```

gives a similar error.

Why is there this inconsistency in row constructor forms between the two uses of `VALUES` in MySQL? Is there a plan to address this in a future version?

By contrast, [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-values.html) works without the explicit `ROW()`.

Comment: Do not mix [VALUES Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/values.html) which needs in row constructor as a value and hence needs in ROW() usage and [INSERT Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html) in INSERT .. VALUES form which allows either values list or row constructors list as a value.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is quite happy (and efficient) with your first form.  What was right after the word "near" in the 1064 error message?

```
INSERT INTO table_name
    (a, b, c)
    VALUES
    (1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9);
```

Comment: Either form works with `INSERT`. The form without `ROW` does not work with bare `VALUES` used in a similar way to `SELECT`.  Examples: `VALUES ROW(1,2);` produces a table output. `VALUES (1,2);` produces a 1064 error that ends with "...near '(1,2)' at line 1".